# Powershell script in background

Tags: google-chrome, powershell, selenium

I have created a script that automates some actions in Chrome.

Is there a way I can run the script without visually opening the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Headless Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome it runs exactly like ordinary chrome, but withour GUI

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the answer.
Is this also possible if i use selenium in powershell?
And if so, how do i do this?

Thanks

Comment: just add the flag `--headless` to the command which Selenium uses to run chrome. Or use a command like options.add_argument('headless')

Comment: Have you followed my link? It says windows support will be available in Chrome 60

Comment: And Chrome 60 is in beta now, so you can try to run your script with a beta version of Chrome